# How can I initialize an array with a length inferred from the variable's type?

Tags: rust

I have a custom type for an array and I want to initialize a variable of that type. It looks something like this:

```
type Registers = [u8; 16];

fn main() {
    let mut registers: Registers;
}
```

I do not want to do something like the following because at some point I may want to change the size of my array type:

```
let mut registers: Registers = [0; 16];
```

Is there any way to use just the name of the type to initialize the variable? Am I forced to specify the initialization just like above?

My question is a bit different from [Can array lengths be inferred in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40107797/155423) because the size of the array should be inferred from the type itself, not the type of the array inferred from the value.

Comment: I believe this question to already be answered by [Is it possible to declare arrays without an explicit length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739088/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences.

Comment: @Shepmaster my question is a bit different. Essentially the size of the array should be inferred by the type itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot infer the length of an array because it is an expression that must be evaluated at compilation time. As far as I can figure, the concept of an "inferred expression" doesn't make sense.

> I may want to change the size of my array type

You can avoid this being a problem by introducing a constant:

```
const N_REGISTERS: usize = 16;
type Registers = [u8; N_REGISTERS];

fn main() {
    let mut registers: Registers = [0; N_REGISTERS];
}
```

You could also use the `Default` implementation of an array, but only for [certain sizes of array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-Default-30) and only if you want the default value of your array's element type:

```
type Registers = [u8; 16];

fn main() {
    let mut registers = Registers::default();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580) are unavailable, `Default` will not be implemented for all array types. This makes array initialization not very ergonomic, as you have experienced.

As a commonly employed alternative, you can turn the type alias into a newtype, with which you can isolate array initialization to a single point in the code.

```
pub struct Registers(pub [u8; 16]);

impl Default for Registers {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Registers([0; 16])
    }
}
```

At this point, and depending on your use case, you can also implement other useful traits for this type, such as `AsRef<u8>` and `AsMut<u8>`.

```
impl AsRef<[u8]> for Registers {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        self.0.as_ref()
    }
}
```